# In Django what is i18n?

Tags: django

I'm looking at [someone else's Django registration templates](https://bitbucket.org/devdoodles/registration_templates/src) and I see the line `{% load i18n %}` in every file. What is `i18n`?

I know it has something to do with [International and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/), but could someone explain it and give a detailed example? Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It loads translation tags such as `{% trans "Text" %}` that could be used in template. If you do not use it you can remove `{% load i18n %}`

When you use `trans` tag for all text that is not dynamic in templates you can then collect all such strings by running `./manage.py makemessages` which creates .po file that would be used for translation.

Comment: Awesome thanks! You gave me enough key words to do some testing and searching on the web to learn more.

Answer (score 8):

`{% load i18n %}` is needed for internationalization. The purpose of internationalization is to allow a single application to read in multiple languages. In order to do this: you need a few hooks called translation strings. To give your template access to these tags, put `{% load i18n %}` toward the top of your template..

Refer to this for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

Answer (score 6):

In order to make a Django project translatable, you have to add a minimal amount of hooks to your Python code and templates. These hooks are called [translation strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#term-translation-string). They tell Django: “This text should be translated into the end user’s language, if a translation for this text is available in that language.” It’s your responsibility to mark translatable strings; the system can only translate strings it knows about.

Django’s internationalization hooks are on by default, and that means there’s a bit of i18n-related overhead in certain places of the framework. If you don’t use internationalization, you should take the two seconds to set [`USE_I18N = False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-USE_I18N) in your settings file. Then Django will make some optimizations so as not to load the internationalization machinery. You’ll probably also want to remove `['django.core.context_processors.i18n']` from your [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) setting.

For more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/